# Find factors of a Mersenne number

Tags: c++, algorithm, primes, factors

On RosettaCode I found this C++ version of modPow (compute 2ᵖ mod n) to find the factors of a Mersenne number.

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <cstdint>
>
> typedef uint64_t integer;
>
> integer bit_count(integer n) {
>     integer count = 0;
>     for (; n > 0; count++)
>         n >>= 1;
>     return count;
> }
>
> integer mod_pow(integer p, integer n) {
>     integer square = 1;
>     for (integer bits = bit_count(p); bits > 0; square %= n) {
>         square *= square;
>         if (p & (1 << --bits))
>             square <<= 1;
>     }
>     return square;
> }
> ```

Do you think this modified version could be faster?

```
const int b=5;

integer mod_2_pow(integer p, integer d) {
    std::vector<int> Residue_p;
    while (p >= 1<<b) {
        Residue_p.push_back((int)(p&((1<<b) -1)));
        p >>= b;
    }
    int nR=Residue_p.size();
    integer mod = 1<<p;
    if(nR>0) {
        for (int i=nR-1; i >=0; i--) {
            for (int j=0; j <b; j++) {
                mod *= mod;
                mod %= d;
            }
            mod <<= Residue_p[i];
            mod %= d;
        }
    }
    else
        mod %= d;
    return mod;
}
```

### Explanation

I think the previous code considers b=1 instead

fix b=5   then 2ᵇ=32

P=P%32  +P/32 *32 = P%32  +b1 *32

b1=b1%32  +b1/32 *32 = P%32  +b2 *32  then b2=b1/32

.....

bm =bm%32  +bm/32 *32

continue until bm/32 <32

the remainder must be stored in a vector [P%32, b1%32, ... , bm%32]

then we start from

mod=2^(bm/32)

the product is repeated for b=5 times

mod=(mod*mod)%D

then it is calculated

mod=(mod* 2^(bm%32) )%D

the whole is repeated for all the remainders in the vector.

Comment: Please provide an explanation of what your code is doing.

Answer (score 1):

This code is:

1. Slower than the original (why do you need two loops? why a vector? boolean operations are much faster)
2. Futile (all factors with 64 bits or smaller, of mersenne numbers with exponents lower than 10G or so, are already known)
3. Probably wrong (didn't completely check it, but storing the bits in a vector to use them like pure bits after, is like scratching your right ear with the left hand going behind your head).

Comment: I don't think you understand how it works, but it is the same as the previous code the number of iterations are almost equal, it is easily adaptable for larger numbers by increasing b, what is avoided is the use of `if`. I wanted to understand if this makes the faster the code.

Comment: @sam, thanks for the edit, I didn't visit this site for a while, and I was not trying to be negative, but this guy bothered mersenneforum last year for a while, posting stupid/incorrect things and refusing to read any number theory, but on the other hand, believing he discovered some breakthrough, ITOW, typical crank.